# Strange artifacts in Swing GUI on mouse hover

Tags: java, swing

I noticed that for some reasons strange artefacts appear in Swing GUI.
This could be observed both when running under Windows and Linux.

Sometimes the artefacts are only a small dot (like in the example below) and another time as a gray box in the size of more or less a cursor prompt [].

Here is an example:

This is an example where everything looks okay:
[image]

Once I hove with my mouse over the GUI and simply wait for lets say one second you can see:
[image]

If I continue to move the mouse the artefact will disappear (and come back where ever I stop moving my mouse within the GUI).

This was also observed over different PCs and also in complete different projects. Therefore I have the feeling this is something related to Java Swing itself!

Does someone is also seeing this and can say how to avoid it?

Comment: Speaking only for myself, I think if you provide a [mcve] so that I can try to reproduce it on my computer, it may help me determine the cause of the behavior you claim to be seeing.

Comment: Sure I will come back with it asap.

Comment: *"I have the feeling this is something related to Java Swing itself!"* I have the feeling this is something related to your code. Looking forward to seeing that MRE..

Comment: I've tried to write a minimal reproducible example w/o success (or in other words w/ success depends on the POV). The artifacts are not there in these examples. Unfortunately this doesn't help me out w/ my current app. Any ideas how to debug such thing(s)?

Comment: *"Any ideas how to debug such thing(s)?"* Tip: Add @Abra (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. **Well, you have a short example that works and a long example that doesn't. I'd recommend one of two approaches** 1) Add code lines to the shorter working code or 2) subtract lines from the longer failing code ..  one or a few lines at a time between tests, until that one change results in a change between working and not working. **That** is a great way to narrow it down to a very specific change that's the difference. Really, if you cannot achieve that ..

Comment: .. debugging, I doubt anyone else will be able to do it for you. These are techniques you'll need to hone and refine to be successful in computer programming.

Comment: Okay calm down. I've never requested that someone else should do it for me. Was just looking for a hint. Anyway ty

Comment: *"Okay calm down."*  Nice one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an empty tooltip (`""`) to me. Try `setToolTipText(null)`.